# Math operations in select clause of WMI Query

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, console-application

In my console application(.NET) i am executing WMI query as follows:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher query;
        ObjectQuery oq;
        ManagementObjectCollection objectCollection;
        try
        {
            oq = new ObjectQuery("SELECT TotalVisibleMemorySize, FreePhysicalMemory FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
            query = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oq);
            objectCollection = query.Get();
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        return objectCollection;
```

I am doing division on the data collected to use in my application. It is working perfectly for me at the moment. 
I am using multiple wmi queries for my application. In order to make a single method to execute all my wmi queries from config I will need to do the division in the select clause of query it self.
I need to execute WMI query like follows:

```
SELECT ((TotalVisibleMemorySize)/1024) as TotalVisibleMemorySize1, ((FreePhysicalMemory)/1024) as FreePhysicalMemory1 FROM Win32_OperatingSystem
```

For this query i am getting error `Invalid query`.
Is there a syntax mistake in this query or is it not possible to do division in the select clause of a WMi query?

Comment: You use aliases with the same names as the columns. Could this cause confusion?

Comment: I have tried with different aliases, but same error. Query edited now for different aliases.

Comment: From the looks of it, WQL is a pretty-well nerfed subset of SQL.  Have you had a look at [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?  Also, [this forum post](http://www.paessler.com/knowledgebase/en/topic/1253-how-can-i-perform-mathematical-operations-in-a-wql-script) points to a solution.

Comment: Why don't you simply divide after fetching values?

Comment: @jonnyGold - from the forum post it looks like math operations are not possible.<br>@Groo - i need to execute multiple queries, read from config file.

Comment: WQL isn't nearly as expressive as SQL is, obviously... I guess you're stuck with doing your math in C#.  You can (and should) hide those queries behind a nice abstraction for your application to use without it worrying about the math and other post-processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems WMI doesn't supports complex queries. Your best bet is to capture wmi results and convert as needed:

```
foreach (ManagementObject mo in objectCollection)
{
Console.WriteLine("Total Memory = {0} MB", 
Convert.ToInt32(mo.GetPropertyValue("TotalVisibleMemorySize"))/1024);
}
```